# Issues with using three div elements and percentages for their width and height size

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div element called `container` and two inner div elements called `firstDiv` and `secondDiv`

the firstDiv will be floating to the left, while the secondDiv will be floating to the right.

I would like the outer div element to take as much width as possible, which means 100% of the available width.

I would also like the two inner elements to take half space, which means 50% of the `container` div.

Here is some basic code for this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        #container{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            border-style:solid;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="firstDiv"> </div>
            <div id="secondDiv"> </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Question 1**

I was expecting a simple solid border to surround the body element, which it seemed like it did, however I got a scroll bar on the y dimension of my browser. Why did this happen? I said I want 100% of body's width and height, and it seems like the browser used more than that.

Now I added the following CSS code:

```
    #firstDiv{
        width:50%;
        height:100%;
        border-style:solid;
        }
```

**Question 2**
it seems like the div takes 50% of the "container" div, however the height seems to be more than 100%. Why did this happen? Picture:
[image]

I do the same for the second div and include the float properties by having the following CSS code:

```
    #container{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        border-style:solid;
    }
    #firstDiv{
        width:50%;
        height:100%;
        border-style:solid;
        float:left;
        }
    #secondDiv{
        width:45%;
        height:100%;
        border-style:solid;
        float:right;
        }
```

**Question 3**
I wanted the two div elements to form a two column page. However again the second div element takes more height than intended like the previous one, and also what's happening is when I resize the browser, the second div goes under the first one.

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borders are not counted when calculating the width of an element. They are supplements to the specified width. This explains your slight inconsistencies. There is no 100% airtight solution to this problem as far as I know that will do *exactly* what you want (close to it, yes, but exactly, no). The most reliable is to use a table, but that isn't a valid solution for designing a page layout as you already certainly know. Another option is to float right and left but have the width specified as either a slightly lower percentage than 50 (such as 48-48) or have a width specified in `px` which would allow you to calculate precisely the exact sizes that you need.

When browsers begin to uniformly implement CSS3, the `box-sizing` property will be able to solve this problem. `box-sizing` specifies what to take into account when calculating the size of an element. Applying `box-sizing:border-box;` will take the border into account, but for the moment this isn't widely enough implemented across browsers to use reliably in your code.

Answer (score 3):

All your questions are due to the box-model you misunderstood.
height: 100% makes the content-height 100%. When you have a border AND height: 100% this leads to 100% + border-width, which obviously is more than 100%.

A possible solution is to use box-sizing: border-box;

The only browser not supporting this property are IE<8. If these are relevant to you, you could create a workaround with CSS-expressions for them. Handle with care!